# Exception is thrown, although I have catch clause for that

Tags: android, exception, kotlin

I have this code:

```
fun String?.toDoubleOrZero(): Double
{
    if (null == this) return 0.0
    return try { this.toDouble() }     // <-- Line #67
    catch (e: NumberFormatException) { 0.0 }
    catch (e: java.lang.NumberFormatException) { 0.0 }  //Just to make sure
}
```

I have clearly handled `NumberFormatException`. I even added Java's `NumberFormatException` to be sure. But still I have many crash reports like this:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "35°45'39.2"N"
       at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
       at java.lang.StringToReal.parseName(StringToReal.java:230)
       at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:254)
       at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
       at *********.toDoubleOrZero(***.kt:67)
       at ...
```

How is this possible and what do I need to do?

**Note:** I can't even reproduce this situation, my code works correctly when I test it, however I have lots of these crash reports in Crashlytics.

**Edit**: I found out that this happens only in HTC devices with Android 4!

Comment: "Note: I can't even reproduce this situation, my code works correctly when I test it, however I have lots of these crash reports in Crashlytics." Are you sure they are from the same version?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yes it happens on all versions of my app, but I just noticed that it happens only on Android 4 and HTC devices!

Answer (score 1):

1. In Kotlin `NumberFormatException` is a `typealias` for `java.lang.NumberFormatException` so you don't need the 2nd.
2. Why bother with exceptions since you already have `toDoubleOrNull()`?

   `fun String?.toDoubleOrZero(): Double {
       val result = this?.toDoubleOrNull()
       return if (result == null) 0.0 else result
   }`
3. I don't believe that your code is the reason for the exception, so put the above code to test and check for exceptions and we'll see.

Comment: Better: `fun String?.toDoubleOrZero(): Double = this?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Of course it is but I prefer when I present code to make it readable by as many as possible, and Kotlin is stil accessible by few.

Comment: On nice, this is a good way to work around that :)
It still bugs me to find out how the exception escapes from the catch clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun String?.toDoubleOrZero(): Double
{
   double value;
     if (null == this) {
        return 0.0 
     }
     return try {
      value = new Double(this.toString()); //typecast your value which is in **this** into double

                 **OR**

    value = Double.valueOf(this); //if **this** is String type;
    }     // <-- Line #67
    catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
      value = 0;
    }
    catch (e: java.lang.NumberFormatException) {
      value = 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: The `Double` class (In kotlin) neither has a constructor which takes String, nor a static method `valueOf`.

Comment: use public inline fun String.toDouble(): Double = java.lang.Double.parseDouble(this).